# Answering low quality questions with quality answers

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

I keep seeing questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553719/how-to-use-powershell-to-change-password-in-ini-file) that are poor quality. Basically something along the lines of :

- "I'm not sure where to start but this is what I want..."
- "Can someone write this code for me...."
- "I need something that can do this.... maybe use (some command)....

or something similar. Questions like these typically are easy to answer however are doing that user and the community a disservice by giving him that answer without him updating the question yes? Thus supporting that we can answer questions like that?

I can't downvote the answer cause it is right and it what I would have answered if the OP showed a little more effort. I will admit, in the past, I have been guilty of answering questions like these as a point grab but I am trying to be a better SO'er.

I don't know how to respond to these answers that shouldn't be there even though they are right.

**Edit before this gets closed**

I understand that there are duplicates but after reading them the two points I would like to make to justitfy keeping this open is

- I used different words to make this question so I didnt find the duplicates in my own search. Other might do the same.
- I agree with the current answer. Editing the question might be a good way to go assuming everything about the answer is up to snuff ( usually needs to be accepted to ensure the edit is the way to go.) Aside from some comments the answers in the dups dont really cover this well. Still reading though as they are large posts.

...nevermind... I though the question might be removed if it was marked as dup.... my comments here might not matter then.

Comment: You can vote any post for any reason. That said, its always a conundrum. Hopefully you *at least* VTC'd the question.

Comment: I downvoted for _lack of research effort_. I was on the fence about the VTC but Too Broad is what I usually use in this case.

Comment: I agree that this is a *major problem*. Don't know how to fix it. They're the perfect questions for low rep inexperienced users to answer to get their rep up. The low quality question asker then accepts the low quality answer, the overall site quality diminishes but there's a net rep increase for low quality contributions even after a smattering of downvotes.

Comment: Turning poop into gold simply encourages more people to post poop. I'd prefer if we started with impure gold at the very least.

Comment: These questions and the natural reaction to them -- "We're not here to do your work" -- are how we got to the _de facto_ requirement that questions include broken attempts, which makes for so many posts being about debugging rather than tasks. In theory, a reasonably-scoped "How do I accomplish X?" should be a good post -- it's quite likely to help future searchers -- but historically, having a place for experienced individuals to ask that opens the door to vampirism and clueless newbs who don't want to think. There's a balance that needs to be struck, and it's almost more work than answering.

Comment: This has been my conundrum. I know I can answer these but i'm under the impression that these are bad questions and we should not help without at least some showing of effort. It also makes my look like an ass if i say "blah blah...we are not a code writing service...blah blah" when someone else just goes and answers anyway. Not all posts need to have code in them but it helps show the user they are trying. Programmers and programming enthusiasts right?

Comment: Right, this is why [the "minimal understanding" close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason?lq=1) was so valuable. See also [How does proof of effort make a question better?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179035)

Comment: Regarding Josh's comment, I tend to evaluate "How do I accomplish X?" questions based on their conformance to other SO norms (no salutations, good spelling/grammar/punctuation).  Answerable conforming questions can get by where poorly-written questions get flagged for closure because they just seem so much worse.  "How do I accomplish X?" isn't always "write some code to do X for me" or "my homework is to do X, please halp".

Comment: I simply downvote / vote to close the question and also downvote any answer, but leaving a comment on the likes of: _Stop spoon feeding people. This will attract more and more useless questions._

Comment: @gnat Regarding the dup. I think there is merit in both of these. There are many useful opinions here as there is there. Also I didnt find that question since I used different key words so hopefully keeping both would be considered an asset.

Comment: @pnuts generally speaking, the only known legitimate [reason to vote down is that Tim lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there is a “middle ground”. Maybe even the majority of the questions I have answered were “poor” – or worse. But whenever my answer is accepted (ie I got lucky with guessing the requirement!) I do go back and check whether the question would seem to benefit from an edit. By the time I have finished editing there may be little left of the original version. But that way OP has an acceptable answer and, hopefully, SO ends up with reasonable quality for such posts.

So, don't "respond to these answers" at all. Instead **edit the question**.

Comment: This is not black and white with non code questions like I already knew. However going back to edit the question regardless of who answered it would be best. OP could see the edit and understand why it was done... hopefully. And the post, then as a whole, would be of better worth for the site.

Comment: Alright I will go back and edit the questions to your answers first then focus on the rest :)

Comment: Touche nuts! I have never been in a habit of looking at old questions until this discussion so i call _its easy to judge in hindsight_