# Disabling answer posting, after spending extensive time, seems annoying

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, answers, on-hold

I spent a lot of time trying to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496740/finding-whether-the-number-is-prime/) which was put on hold. You may be asking why I tried to answer this question, so I'll say:

1. When I started, the question wasn't on hold.
2. This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496740/finding-whether-the-number-is-prime#comment58686006_35496740) stated that: "You haven't asked anything resembling a question. You haven't even said if your code is working or not." I see what @meagar means, but after [fiddling](https://jsfiddle.net/) with it, I could see multiple problems with the supplied code, which I addressed.

So, I think it is fine to disabling answering on a question that is [on hold], but I think that it is unfair to disable the <kbd>Post Your Answer</kbd> button once a user has spent time trying to answer the question.

Is my problem unreasonable?

Comment: Attempting to answer very low quality questions is gamble, you've lost this time (which is good and desired outcome, some discussion why - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280683/answering-low-quality-questions-with-quality-answers). Consider this to be an exercise in reading someone else's code and move on to better questions.

Comment: [How to decide which questions I should not answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254549/839601)

Answer (score 8):

> I am now waiting for the post to be fixed

Wait, what? You just said…

> I see what @meagar means, but after fiddling with it, I could see multiple problems with the supplied code, which I addressed.

That says to me that you actually took the time to do the work the asker was supposed to have done in advance. Now, I don't know why you wasted the time to do that, but since you did, you are in a perfect position to edit the question and fix its problems. In other words, you can turn it into a real question. You don't have to "wait" for the post to get fixed.

And, of course, once it's fixed, the process of getting it re-opened proceeds much more quickly.

> So, I think it is fine to disabling answering on a question that is [on hold], but I think that it is unfair to disable the Post Your Answer button once a user has spent time trying to answer the question.

I disagree that we need a special case here. How should the system know how much time you've spent trying to answer the question? Lots of people compose answers in the IDE of their choice, rather than in the textbox on the page. How should that time be taken into account?

More to the point, by closing unclear questions, we are trying to save other people the time that you have invested in this one. You have already admitted that the question was unclear to you at first, and how you can see what the people who voted to close it were thinking.

If you really saw a gem in the question that early, you should have edited it *first*, before spending time on an answer. If you didn't see any redeeming value in the question before spending a lot of time answering it, then I guess I would just ask that, in the future, you spend your time more wisely, investing more heavily in answering *high-quality* questions, rather than low-quality ones.

Of course, you are welcome to answer any questions you want. But, as has been pointed out already, you took a gamble in trying to answer a low-quality question.

Comment: I agree with you with most of those things :), although, I am still not convinced that the "Post Your Answer" button should be disabled. Side note: I actually [have tried](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317235/the-suffering-of-a-question-based-on-the-limited-context-of-many/) to edit it. "I am now waiting for the post to be fixed" was a mistake. Remember, that I'm not a veteran.

Answer (score -7):

As I know, there is a special case already. As soon as you didn't close or reload the tab, you can post the answer even if the question is put on hold.

---

[Question](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1971/178988) about this possibility on metaRuSO (in Russian).

[Timeline](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/473356/timeline) fragment for the question mentioned there:

```
2015-12-10 08:09:51Z   answered
2015-12-10 07:25:32Z   closed
```

Comment: I think this is wrong. The "Post Your Answer" button was grayed out after the post was put on hold.

Comment: @Mirabilis, if I find that topic, I'll add a link to it and question history.

Comment: Okay, but maybe they have changed it? Thanks anyway :).

Comment: @Mirabilis, you can use your browser developer console to re-enable the button, and it'll let you post just fine.

Comment: @Mirabilis, added the links.

Comment: Could anybody explain why minuses?

Comment: 1. I am 99% sure that there is no special case 2. The question nor the timeline make any sense.

Comment: @Mirabilis, 1. The question tells that answering closed question is possible if you didn't reload the page. 2. The timeline shows that answer was added 44 minutes after the question was closed. Because of that thee was a question asked on meta - how is it possible to answer after putting the question on hold.